# Creating x-jet-dialog modal and x-jet-confirmation modal not working together

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-jetstream

in my index.blade.php

```
<div class="flex mb-4">
        <x-jet-button wire:click="$toggle('savePositionModal')" wire:loading.attr="enabled">pAdd New Position
        </x-jet-button>
        @include('livewire.admin.manageelections.electionpositions.positionmodal')
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
        <div class="p-6 px-20 bg-white border-b border-gray-200 rounded-full">
            @include('livewire.admin.manageelections.electionpositions.positionstable')
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Position Modal was working fine. but when the confirmation modal which is found in positions.table

```
 @foreach($positions as $position)
    <tr>
        <td class="border p-1">{{$count++}}</td>
        <td class="border p-1">{{$position->name}}</td>
        <td class="border p-1">{{$position->description}}</td>
        <td class="border p-1 text-center">
            <x-jet-secondary-button wire:click="openPositionModal({{$position->id}})" wire:loading.attr="enabled">
                Edit
            </x-jet-secondary-button>
            <x-jet-danger-button wire:click="$toggle('deletePositionModal')" wire:loading.attr="enabled">
                Delete
            </x-jet-danger-button>
            @include('livewire.admin.manageelections.electionpositions.deletePositonModal')
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

the open Position modal is also working. but the confirmation modal (which is for Deleting purposes) is not working..

doe's anyone has any idea that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one modal can be included in laravel livewire jetstream.

I recommend switching what modal to include if the user clicks a certain button.

so the default state of every modal is active or open. if ever the user click the "click-to-include-modal-button" the modal is included and then opens automatically.